# span indenting in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html

- I am building a span10 Bootstrap based website.
- Inside the footer are 3 divs all under each other, all span10.
- The second and third divs are indenting.
- I don't know why. Can someone please help?

See the site here - http://www.brainstormadvertising.co.uk/webDev/

The green area in the footer is where we see the first indent occuring

This footer is within and overall div with the container-fluid class. Here is the footer code:

```
<footer class="row-fluid backgAll img-rounded">

    <div class="span10 topCorners">
        <img src="customImages/headerTop.png" alt="H2onics">
    </div>

    <div class="span10 green">Footer content goes here</div>

    <div class="span10 bottomCorners">
        <img src="customImages/footerBottom.png" alt="H2onics">
    </div>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
<footer class="backgAll img-rounded">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 topCorners">
        <img src="customImages/headerTop.png" alt="H2onics">
    </div><!-- end span10 -->
  </div><!-- end row-fluid -->

  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 green">
        Footer content goes here
    </div><!-- end span10 -->
  </div><!-- end row-fluid -->

   <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span10 bottomCorners">
        <img src="customImages/footerBottom.png" alt="H2onics">
   </div><!-- end span10 -->
  </div><!-- end row-fluid -->

</footer>
```

Note that I'm wrapping all the span10 divs in row-fluid divs

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That worked and it is an option I had considered. But still seems strange. If they are span10, they would simply by equivalent to width:100% and not indent like the site did. But thank you all the same.

Comment: @William If you look at how the grid is defined, the container defines the overall width of the page, with a little padding left and right. Each .span div also has some padding on the left to space the columns. If this was all there was there would be a double space on the left of the first column, so Bootstrap compensates by adding a negative left margin to pull the first column to the left a bit. Thats why you needed to do this and have the columns align.

Comment: @William I just noticed that you have a blip in the block where you have 5 columns. It shows up when you narrow the browser window. At the moment you have nested the 5 span2 divs inside a span10. See the fluid nesting section on http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html for details on how to do this. Good luck!